# I can only access my auth()->user() in the method where I auth()->login() and not the other methods in the same Controller

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to implement my own login/logout with passport in a new Controller.

```
class AuthController extends AccessTokenController
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
.
.
```

My login methods works fine:

```
public function login(ServerRequestInterface $request)
    {
        if (!auth()->attempt([
            'email' => $request->getParsedBody()['email'],
            'password' => $request->getParsedBody()['password']
        ])) {
            return response()->json('failed attempt...');
        }
        auth()->login(User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first());
        .
        .
        // I can access auth()->user() here just fine ..
    }
```

But I can't access the authenticated user in the logout method so I can get his tokens and delete them.

```
public function logout()
    {
        //I can't access the authenticated user here
        return auth()->user();

        //return response()->json('Logged out successfully', 200);
    }
```

**What am I doing wrong?
Note: I left out anything in the login method that is related to issuing a token because it's not related to the question ..**

Update: my routes/api.php

```
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');
```

Comment: are you sending authorization header? try dumping your headers

Comment: Please add your routes/api.php

Comment: @SalmanZafar No I'm not sending Authorization in my headers for the logout request, but I don't think that's what's blocking me from accessing the authenticated user ..

Comment: @Lotfi if your are using api then you should send authorization header else it should work for session based authenticated

Comment: @SalmanZafar Thank you, that solved it.
I sent the Authorization in the header, then accessed the user via
`
return $request->user();
`

Comment: @Lotfi happy to help. I just posted it as an aswer kindly mark as accepted so other can also get benfit from it. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using `api` then you should send `authorization header` else it should work for `session` based `authentication`

Then you can access the authenticated user using the request

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
  return $request->user(); //the user that made the request (the authenticated user)
}
```

**Or:**

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
   return Auth::user(); //the user that made the request (the authenticated user)
}
```